# STM32 Nucleo f401RE 1.44 inch OLED ST7735

Tags: stm32, display, nucleo, oled

I try to drive ST7735 OLED display with nucleo board. I worked with a ready-made example I found on the internet, but I could not print anything to the screen. When I compile my code, I don't get any errors and my screen is getting power. Is there a point I missed in the SPI settings?

[enter link description here](https://controllerstech.com/st7735-1-8-tft-display-with-stm32/)

Some friends suggested adding SPI DMA TX, I tried but the result did not change. Do I need to enter an extra parameter in the DMA settings?

[image]

Comment: Honestly, if you're having problems driving your display without DMA, why add extra complexity? First you make it work without DMA, then you add DMA on top of it. DMA is a complex peripheral. Take a step back. Get the datasheet of the display's driver IC, check what and how example code initializes.

Comment: you're right, I already tried it without using dma, it didn't work, someone solved the problem by adding dma as a solution, so I added dma. thank you for your advice.